# Catch mongoose saveAsync error

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I am trying to upload a file to a static folder and save entry info to mongodb using mongoose. One possible scenario is that only one of the tasks works and then I need to revert the finished task. The designed workflow is to upload file first and save data to db after file uploaded. Here's the code:

```
    Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose);

    /**
     * Upload file
     * @property {string} req.body.filename
     * @property {tar file} req.file
     */
    function _upload(req, res) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        multerMiddleware(req, res, err => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve(req.body);
        });
      });
    }

    /**
     * Create new entry
     * @property {string} req.body.name
     * @returns {Entry}
     */
    function create(req, res, next) {
      let entry;

      _upload(req, res)
        .then(body => {
          entry = new Entry({
            name: body.name
          });

          debug(`start to saving entry`);
          return entry.saveAsync();
          });
        }).then(savedEntry => {
          debug(savedEntry);
          entry = savedEntry;
          res.json(savedEntry);
        }).catch(e => {
          // TODO: if save failed, remove file
          console.error(e);
          return next(e);
        });
    }

    const router = express.Router();  // eslint-disable-line new-cap

    router.route('/')
      /** POST /api/entries - create new entry */
      .post(create);
```

Curl command:

```
curl -i  -F "name=w69325"  -F "file=@entry_file.tar"  http://localhost:3000/api/entrys
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
// after a while
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However, when I stopped mongo service before api is called, the program just hang. My intention was to test error handling in which case upload success but save fail. My understanding that any error happens in the promise chain should be catched by catch clause. But that didn't happen.. Program just lost in nowhere..

Where did I get wrong? Any help is appreciated!